# Database contents setting themselves to 0

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a Database that contains 4 tables, however I'm using 1 of them which is separated from the others.

In this table I have 4 fields which are varchar and the rest are ints (11 other fields), when the users fill up the DB everything gets saved correctly, however it has happened 3 times so far that the database values for the int's reset to 0 without any apparent reason. At first, I thought, it was because those fields (where the numbers should go) were varchars not ints. However since I changed it, it happened again. I've already double checked my code and I have nothing that even updates or inserts a 0 value. Also I'm using codeigniter and active records which protect against SQL injections AND have XSS filtering enabled, could anyone point out something I might be missing or a reason for this to be happening?

Also, I'm pretty sure about the answer of this but, is there ANY way to recover some data?? Other than having to ask everyone to fill in everything again.. =/

** EDIT **

The Storage Engine is MyISAM and Collation is latin1_swedish_ci, Pack Keys are default, for all intents and purposes it's a normal DB

** EDIT **

Here's my Table Structure

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Feb 10, 2011 at 09:31 AM
-- Server version: 5.0.51
-- PHP Version: 5.2.14

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `cinesdec_prueba`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Oscar`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Oscar` (
  `Id` int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Nombre` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `ApPaterno` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `ApMaterno` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Edad` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `Twitter` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `Correo` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  `BestPicture` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ActorLead` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ActorSupport` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ActressLead` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ActressSupport` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Art` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Directing` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Foreing` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Music` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Visual` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Desempate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Correo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=89 ;
```

Comment: SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'; and look on the log about the queries he runs

Comment: it's a rented server and I don't have root access, but I'll ask the admin to help me out =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've described, it sounds like your default value for the fields is 0.

You may have created your table with the defaults in there, like so:

```
`[column_name]` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

To remove the default, do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `[table_name]` CHANGE `[column_name]` `[column_name]` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Which will remove the default 0 value (note the removal of `DEFAULT '0'`).

**The reason you're seeing the 0s:** When the default value is 0, if your INSERT statements don't include the field, MySQL will just insert the default value into the field.

I'm guessing the software you used to create the table automatically added the 0 values, which typically aren't a problem as any related table's id would start at 1 which is the most common value for an integer value.

Comment: I tried to run it I get a syntax error, I'm not sure where exactly sorry I'm plainly asking but I am really rusty with handling DBs, also, if this is typically not the issue, why would it be affecting me now? (just looking for an explanation as to why this is happening)

Comment: see my "reason you're seeing the 0s"

Comment: As for the syntax error, did you change the table and column names? I just added some place holders.

Comment: yes I did the only difference I can see is that between each column_name I had a comma added by phpmyadmin itself, I however also tried without the comma, this is my query (the ` does not appear because of how it's parsed when I write the comment but they are there)

ALTER TABLE `Oscar` CHANGE `BestPicture`, `ActorLead`, `ActorSupport`, `ActressLead`, `ActressSupport`, `Art`, `Directing`, `Foreing`, `Music`, `Visual`, `Desempate` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL

Comment: It might also be helpful, if possible, if you add your full table structure to your question.

Comment: Well, from your table structure, you already don't have the defaults set to 0. The problem is something else then. What are the INSERT statements that you're running?

Comment: They just inserted the values, I found the problem apparently, when you used the URI to load the site directly it tried to post empty values and somehow updated every single row to a 0 due to the fact that the post contained nothing at all...thanks for all the help =) really helped me out debugging this

Answer (score 0):

What [SQL_MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html) are you using? You need at least STRICT_ALL_TABLES but TRADITIONAL and ANSI might be even better to get a reliable database.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='traditional,ansi';
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

Comment: I have SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; would that be a problem?

Comment: I don't think that will change anything, NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO is about the auto_increment not about other fields.